# Is it possible to write custom .shortcut file for iOS Shortcuts application?

Tags: ios, iphone, sirishortcuts, ios-shortcut

#### Why?

I have REST API service where user can place marks on any day of the year. There is Endpoint (URL) that allows user to place mark on current day, for example `POST` request to `/api/mark/1`

So, I want to create custom .shortcut file for users that has command to visit that particular endpoint (including user access_token)

#### Question

So, there is app [Shortcuts](https://apps.apple.com/app/shortcuts/id915249334) for iPhone.
There is option to export shortcut as file of `.shortcut` format.

I am curious is there any way I can write my own `.shortcut` files using text editor? (VSCode for example)

I tried googling about this topic, but, unfortunately, didn't find any answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of .shortcut files are binary plist files signed by Apple (try exporting a file from the shortcuts app and looking at it), so it appears the answer is, generally, no.

Answer (score 0):

After searching web, closest thing I could find is JS library [Shortcuts.fun](https://shortcuts.fun/)